# Generate a random number doesnt work when calling function twice

Tags: c, function, random, srand

I am trying to get 2 different types of numbers/colors when I am calling my function twice, but it does not work. I've seeded the numbers/function but its still not working.

Here's how my code looks:

```
    #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define DIAMONDS 0
#define CLUBS 1
#define HEARTS 2
#define SPADES 3
#define JACK 11
#define QUEEN 12
#define KING 13
#define ACE 1
#define COLOR_SIZE 13
#define NR_OF_SUITS 4
#define DECK_SIZE 52


struct Card
{
    int suit;
    int value;
};

void printCards(struct Card *cardDeck);
void swapCards(struct Card *cardA, struct Card *cardB);
void shuffleCards(struct Card *cardDeck);
void printOneCards(struct Card *cardDeck);

int main()
{
    //struct Card deck[DECK_SIZE];      //Statiskt allokerad array
    struct Card * deck; //Dynamiskt allokerad array
    int index;
    int suit_index;

    deck = (struct Card *)malloc(sizeof(struct Card) * DECK_SIZE);
    for (suit_index = 0; suit_index < NR_OF_SUITS; suit_index++)    /* Initiera kortleken */
        for (index = 0; index < COLOR_SIZE; index++)
        {
            deck[suit_index*COLOR_SIZE + index].suit = suit_index;
            deck[suit_index*COLOR_SIZE + index].value = index;
        }
    printCards(deck);
    shuffleCards(deck);
    printCards(deck);
    printf("\n");
    printOneCards(deck);
    printf("Dealers cards\n");
    srand(time(NULL));
    printOneCards(deck);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void printCards(struct Card *cardDeck)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < DECK_SIZE; i++)
    {
        switch (cardDeck[i].value + 1)
        {
        case ACE: printf("Ace ");
            break;
        case JACK: printf("Jack ");
            break;
        case QUEEN: printf("Queen");
            break;
        case KING: printf("King ");
            break;
        default: printf("%d ", cardDeck[i].value + 1);
            break;
        }
        printf("of ");
        switch (cardDeck[i].suit)
        {
        case DIAMONDS: printf("Diamonds ");
            break;
        case HEARTS: printf("Hearts ");
            break;
        case CLUBS: printf("Clubs ");
            break;
        case SPADES: printf("Spades ");
            break;
        default: printf("Something went wrong!! ");
            break;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void swapCards(struct Card * cardA, struct Card *cardB)
{
    struct Card temp;
    temp = *cardA;
    *cardA = *cardB;
    *cardB = temp;
}

void shuffleCards(struct Card *cardDeck)
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    for (int i = 0; i < DECK_SIZE; i++)
        swapCards(&cardDeck[i], &cardDeck[rand() % 52]);
}
void printOneCards(struct Card *cardDeck)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        switch (cardDeck[i].value + 1)
        {
        case ACE: printf("Ace ");
            break;
        case JACK: printf("Jack ");
            break;
        case QUEEN: printf("Queen");
            break;
        case KING: printf("King ");
            break;
        default: printf("%d ", cardDeck[i].value + 1);
            break;
        }
        printf("of ");
        switch (cardDeck[i].suit)
        {
        case DIAMONDS: printf("Diamonds ");
            break;
        case HEARTS: printf("Hearts ");
            break;
        case CLUBS: printf("Clubs ");
            break;
        case SPADES: printf("Spades ");
            break;
        default: printf("Something went wrong!! ");
            break;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

So when I am calling the function `printonecards()`, it prints out 2 randomly cards and colors the first time, but the second time i call it, it does not.
How do I fix this problem and how do I make it properly work?

Comment: @l3x are you sure this is a good dupe?

Comment: @ l3x I'm reopening this question as the marked dupe maybe related, but not an exact answer to this question. Let me know if you think otherwise. :)

Comment: Still no answer that works. Tried the methods below but not working.

Answer (score 2):

You call `srand` a couple of times at the start of multiple functions. `srand` seeds the random number generator and should only be called when you wish to reset the random number generator. When you call `srand` using `time(NULL)` as the seed multiple times in the same second (which is quite possible considering current hardware), you will use the same seed with a clean random number generator. This will generate the same number multiple times.

The way to solve this is moving your call to `srand` to the start of `main`, then remove it in all other functions. This way your random number generator will be set exactly one, and won't be reset, producing more random numbers.

EDIT:

Another problem I didn't notice the first time, is that you pass the same argument to the function `printOneCards`, namely the argument `deck`. This argument doesn't differ between the cards of the player and the cards of the dealer, meaning the function will print the same deck twice.

Since a player always seems to have 2 cards, you can use pointer arithmetic to change this. Your function calls will then become:

```
printOneCards(deck); //Print the first and second card
printf("Dealers cards\n");
printOneCards(deck+2); //Print the third and fourth card
```

This way you will get different results for both the player and the dealer, as you intended.

Comment: Ive tried as you've written in your answer. but it still doesnt work.
I have removed srand from all other functions except main, but it still gives me the same sequence of numbers.

Comment: Did you move srand to the top of main? Try writing it as the first action you take in main.

Comment: Yep, i've done that. It doesnt matter though, if i still call the function twice it gives me nothing but the same two numbers printed.

Comment: Edited so you won't have that problem anymore.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** You need to seed the PRNG (Pseudo Random Number Generator) only once at the start of your program. Remove `srand(time(NULL));` from the functions and put it into your `main()`.

To elaborate, `time(NULL)` has a *time granularity of 1 second*. which means, if called multiple times within 1 second, it will return the same value. This way, you'll end up seeding the PRNG with same value again and again and thus, the pseudo random numbers generated by `rand()` will be same.

That's why, you need to remove the seeding part from your called function to avoid re-seeding the PNRG.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `srand()` **all time you need to seed a new random number**. If you put the `srand(time(NULL))` on **for loop** or **while loop**, maybe you get what you want.